# How to iterate over the last element of array while comparing current element with next element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, arrow-functions

I have an array which contains key-value pairs. Keys are (ID, Lat, Lon).

What I am trying to do is compare current element ID with next element ID and if they are equal put the Lat and Lon of the current element in an object (in my case "point") and call a function (InjectIntoArray on that point which initializes a global array points[]).

When condition becomes false (i.e current id not equals next id), in else part I am putting the current elements Lat and Lon in a object and calling a function on that one, this is because the ID of next element is going to be different and I have to get all the Lat and Lon of current element ID.

The problem occurs when the last element is being checked, it exits without obtaining the last record.(i.e list[lastElement]).

How can I get the Lat and Lon of all elements? Is there any better way to achieve this?

Here is my array -

```
var list = [
            { id: 100, Lat: 19.25, Lon: 74}, { id: 100, Lat: 19.79, Lon: 74.19 }, 
            { id: 101, Lat: 19.99, Lon:75.10 }, { id: 101, Lat: 20.37, Lon:68.9}, 
            { id: 119, Lat: 17, Lon: 70 }, { id: 107, Lat: -16, Lon: -165 }, 
            { id: 107, Lat: -15, Lon: -150 }
           ];
```

And the code-

```
for (let i = 0; i < list.length - 1;i++) {
   if (list[i].id == list[i+1].id) {
      var point = { LATITUDE: list[i].Lat, LONGITUDE: list[i].Lon };
      InjectIntoArray(point);
   }
   else {
       var point = { LATITUDE: list[i].Lat, LONGITUDE: list[i].Lon };
       InjectIntoArray(point);
       plotRoute(false,2);
       points = [];
  }

}
```

Comment: Is that really your code that is working except for the last element part? It looks like you're not doing anything with `points`, and the only difference is `plotRoute`

Comment: Really confusing, same code exists in if and else condition, why don't you take out of that code from both conditions?. As per my understanding, you aren't doing any operation for last element. You have to add one more condition for last element ploting.

Comment: @CertainPerformance `points` array is a global variable which is fed by `InjectIntoArray()` function which puts a single point at a time in `points` array. `plotRoute()` function will get all the elements from `points` array and plot them on the map.

Comment: @YogeshPatel Code is redundant in else part because when I detect that next element ID is different I have get the current elements Lat and Lon properties as they belong to current element ID and not the next element. then call `plotRoute()` and make the global array `points[ ]` empty for next new elements Lat and Lon values.

Comment: How can I do this in better approach please point me  in a direction.

Comment: please add an example of `InjectIntoArray` and `plotRoute` as well as the intital value of `points`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the best here is to use the reduce function:

```
var list = [ // list from the example in original question
        { id: 100, Lat: 19.25, Lon: 74}, { id: 100, Lat: 19.79, Lon: 74.19 }, 
        { id: 101, Lat: 19.99, Lon:75.10 }, { id: 101, Lat: 20.37, Lon:68.9}, 
        { id: 119, Lat: 17, Lon: 70 }, { id: 107, Lat: -16, Lon: -165 }, 
        { id: 107, Lat: -15, Lon: -150 }
       ];
allRoutes = list.reduce(function(routes,e){
   if (!routes[e.id]) routes[e.id] = [];
   routes[e.id].push({LATITUDE: e.Lat, LONGITUDE: e.Lon});
   return routes;
}, {})
```

this way you get an object with all "routes" assigned to their IDs.

```
{
  100: [{ "LATITUDE": 19.25, "LONGITUDE": 74    }, 
        { "LATITUDE": 19.79, "LONGITUDE": 74.19 }],
  101: [{ "LATITUDE": 19.99, "LONGITUDE": 75.1  }, 
        { "LATITUDE": 20.37, "LONGITUDE": 68.9  }],
  107: [{ "LATITUDE": -16,   "LONGITUDE": -165  }, 
        { "LATITUDE": -15,   "LONGITUDE": -150  }],
  119: [{ "LATITUDE": 17,    "LONGITUDE": 70    }]
}
```

Now you can iterate over the routes and plot them one by one, for example in the following way:

```
plotRoute = function(r){ console.log('plotting route: ', r) }
Object.values(allRoutes).map(plotRoute)
```

Cheers, iPirat

Comment: Thank you , that worked very well. Appreciate everyone's efforts

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but how about:

```
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

     if (i == (list.length - 1)) {
        // do what you want to do with the last one
     }
     else if (list[i].id == list[i+1].id) {
        var point = { LATITUDE: list[i].Lat, LONGITUDE: list[i].Lon };
        InjectIntoArray(point);
     }
     else {
        var point = { LATITUDE: list[i].Lat, LONGITUDE: list[i].Lon };
        InjectIntoArray(point);
        plotRoute(false,2);
        points = [];
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you mark I have this approach in mind but we should be able to do better than this.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are pretty bad practice, and without seeing more of the code it's hard to refactor more, but one option would be to have a persistent variable indicating the current `id` being iterated over. When the `id` changes, call `plotRoute` and reassign `points`. Use `forEach` and destructure the arguments to reduce syntax noise:

```
let currentId = null;
function setupNewId(id) {
  currentId = id;
  plotRoute(false,2);
  points = [];
}
list.forEach(({ id, Lat: LATITUDE, Lon: LONGITUDE }) => {
  if (id !== currentId) setupNewId(id);
  InjectIntoArray({ LATITUDE, LONGITUDE });
});
```

As you can see, here we're reassigning `points` and calling `plotRoute` at the *beginning* of a new iteration, not at the end, so there are no off-by-one problems like the one you were having.